# How to detect UnloadPackage from the target BPL?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-2007

Is there a part of code which is executed when a [dynamic package](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178) is unloaded calling `UnloadPackage` function?

```
var
  MyPackageHandle : THandle;
begin
  MyPackageHandle := LoadPackage('.\MyPackage.bpl');
  if(MyPackageHandle <> 0) then 
    UnloadPackage(MyPackageHandle);
end;
```

In this case, I need to execute some code inside *MyPackage.bpl* when it's unloaded

Comment: Do `initialization` and `finalization` work in this case maybe?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the bug properly?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that you should put code that needs to be called when your package is unloaded into the `finalization` part of your unit. I know from your other package that you're trying to unload a dll. But the catch is that should never load/unload a dll from `initialization` or `finalization`.

So what you need to do is have a function in your package that you will call from your main application, that performs the clean-up.

```
type
  TCleanup = procedure;
var
  MyPackageHandle : THandle;
  CleanupProc: TCleanup;
begin
  MyPackageHandle := LoadPackage('.\MyPackage.bpl');
  if(MyPackageHandle <> 0) then
  begin
    @CleanupProc := GetProcAddress(MyPackageHandle, 'Cleanup' );
    if @CleanupProc <> nil then
      CleanupProc;
    UnloadPackage(MyPackageHandle);
  end;
end;
```